# Django widgets: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to create edition form for selected User of my customUser model, but unfortunately this is what I get while getting the form:

```
ValueError at /changeCustomUser/ too many values to unpack
```

which traces me to both template and views file - I'll mark in code error places.

models.py

```
class CustomUserManager(UserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return UserManager.create_user(self, username, email=email, password=password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        return UserManager.create_superuser(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields)

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    role = models.CharField(max_length = 1, default = 'C')

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        swappable = 'My_app.CustomUser'
```

forms.py

```
class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    def __init__(self, choices_list, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomUserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if choices_list:
            self.fields['role']=forms.ChoiceField(label='Function', choices=choices_list, widget=forms.Select, required = True)
        del self.fields['password']
        del self.fields['username']

    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('first_name', 'role')
```

views.py

```
def changeCustomUser(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        customUserChangeForm = CustomUserChangeForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if customUserChangeForm.is_valid():
            customUserChangeForm.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/changeCustomUser/?customUser=saved')
        else:
            e1 = str(request.user)
            if e1 == 'AnonymousUser':
                context1={'welcome_id': 'Welcome Guest :)', 'form': 'Log in to change user details', 'error': ''}
            else:
"""ERROR TRACE"""
                context1={'welcome_id': 'Welcome '+request.user.first_name + ' :)', 'form': customUserChangeForm,'error': 'Make data valid'}
            return render_to_response('changeCustomUser.html', context1 ,context_instance=RequestContext(request)) 
    else:
        e1 = str(request.user)
        if e1 == 'AnonymousUser':
            context1={'welcome_id': 'Welcome Guest', 'error': ''}
        else:
            if request.user.role == 'A':
                customUserChangeForm = CustomUserChangeForm(initial = {'first_name': request.user.first_name, 'role': request.user.role}, 
                choices_list=[('A', 'B', 'C')]
                )
            elif request.user.role == 'B':
                customUserChangeForm = CustomUserChangeForm(initial = {'first_name': request.user.first_name, 'role': request.user.role}, 
                choices_list=[('B', 'C')]
                )

            if request.GET.get('customUser', '') == 'saved':
                context1={'welcome_id': 'Welcome '+request.user.first_name + ' :)', 'form': customUserChangeForm,'error': 'Details changed succesfully.'}
            else:
                context1={'welcome_id': 'Welcome '+request.user.first_name + ' :)', 'form': customUserChangeForm,'error': ''}        # SECOND ERROR TRACE
        return render_to_response('changeCustomUser.html', context1 ,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

changeCustomUser.html

```
{# Other fields declared as follows, but without role conditions: #}
{% if user.role == "A" or user.role == "B" %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form.role.label_tag }}</td>
"""ERROR TRACE"""
        <td>{{ form.role }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endif %}
```

Like you see, I'm setting my own privileges in "role" field and different roles can perform different changes. Coming back to problem:
I've tried to switch request.user for a while by passing a variable from previous view:

```
if request.GET.get('username_get', '') != '':
    sub_user = Reader.objects.get(username=str(request.GET.get('username_get', '')))
else:
    sub_user = request.user
```

That helped me at least display proper data of user I selected to change. Sadly - that user switch lasts only until i hit POST, because of lost of this passed argument, with the same error result as presented above(too many values to unpack). All I managed to get is editing logged user instead of the user I selected to edit.
I've tried of course to figure out why these values are wrong, but web-search only confirmed they need to stay in a tuple format so select widget can handle them.
Any ideas how to operate on selected users with 'A'/'B' role?

**EDIT:** My bad. Sorry, for not being careful. I'm saying above about tuples and yet not providing ones. I've got them like you said:

```
choices_list=[('A','A'),  ('B','B'), ('C', 'C')]
```

Single choices_list did not work either. Thanks for very useful tips. I'll improve my code immediately. As there is no problem with that specific part of choices_list - a full traceback below:

```
Environment:
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/changeCustomUser/
Django Version: 1.7.1
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'My_app')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /var/www/html/DjangoApps/My_app/templates/changeCustomUser.html, error at line 22
   too many values to unpack
   16 :     <td>{{ form.email.label_tag }}</td>
   17 :     <td>{{ form.email }}</td>
   18 : </tr>
   19 : {% if user.role == "A" or user.role == "B" %}
   20 : <tr>
   21 :     <td>{{ form.role.label_tag }}</td>
   22 :     <td> {{ form.role }} </td>
   23 : </tr>
   24 : {% endif %}
   25 : <tr>
   26 :     <td>{{ form.user_address.label_tag }}</td>
   27 :     <td>{{ form.user_address }}</td>
   28 : </tr>
   29 : </table>

Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/var/www/html/DjangoApps/My_app/views.py" in changeCustomUser
  88.             return render_to_response('changeCustomUser.html', context1 ,context_instance=RequestContext(request)) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/shortcuts.py" in render_to_response
  23.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  178.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in render
  148.             return self._render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in _render
  142.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  126.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in _render
  142.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  65.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  312.                 return nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/debug.py" in render
  93.             output = force_text(output)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/utils/encoding.py" in force_text
  85.                 s = six.text_type(s)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/forms/forms.py" in __str__
  508.         return self.as_widget()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/forms/forms.py" in as_widget
  560.         return force_text(widget.render(name, self.value(), attrs=attrs))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/forms/widgets.py" in render
  504.         options = self.render_options(choices, [value])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/forms/widgets.py" in render_options
  530.         for option_value, option_label in chain(self.choices, choices):

Exception Type: ValueError at /changeCustomUser/
Exception Value: too many values to unpack
```

PS Found three typos. Sorry, but after whole night of tries to make it work, I might not be as focused as I should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally - I won that battle.

It had no rights to work properly in my previous construction.

First of all - I needed to create variable "choices_list" in my POST request.method "if" block. Here was the clou. Then and only then I could create my customUserChangeForm adding one more argument in constructor:

```
customUserChangeForm = CustomUserChangeForm(choices_list, request.POST, instance=sub_user)
```

Last thing to do was passing a username of user which was being edited to this "if" from GET parameter and making instance of a sub_user for proper username and matching of course proper choices_list values.

Thanks again for help and tips.

PS Error traceback was not really as specific as it should and actually pointed at wrong place in views.py file.

Answer (score 5):

Please post the *full* traceback - but I suspect your problem is with this line:

```
 choices_list=[('A', 'B', 'C')]
```

A choices list is supposed to be sequence (list or whatever) of `(value, label)` pairs. Replace the above with:

```
 choices_list=[('A','A'),  ('B','B'), ('C', 'C')]
```

as well as this (which is interpreted as a single choice list with value 'B' and label 'C'):

```
choices_list=[('B', 'C')]
```

with:

```
choices_list=[('B', 'B'), ('C', 'C')]
```

As a side note:

Read the doc about django auth and `request.user`: you can replace this

```
e1 = str(request.user)
if e1 == 'AnonymousUser':
    do_something()
```

with

```
if request.user.is_anonymous():
    do_something()
```

Learn to use python's string formating features - you can replace this:

```
'Welcome '+request.user.first_name + ' :)'
```

with

```
'Welcome %s :)' % request.user.first_name
```

or better: leave the presentation to the template layer (where it belongs), remember that with the default settings you'll get access to `request.user` in your template's context without having to explicitely pass it.

Learn to properly factor your code to avoid repetitions : you have the same code blocks copy-pasted in different places, which is brittle at best (FWIW you already have one place with a typo, see if you can find it).

And finally: learn to use Django's Messages application (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/messages/) instead of reinventing the squared wheel.

Comment: Edit section added with a full traceback. Problem still exists. Any other ideas?

Comment: The error being on "for option_value, option_label in chain(self.choices, choices"... You obviously still have a wrong choice list somewhere. If you don't know where your best bet is probably to add some debugging code around that line in Django's source code.